# Custom Blazor Select Option - not selecting initial item from bound value

Tags: html-select, blazor, custom-component

While creating custom components I wanted to extend the Select with a custom Option component, so that I can add extra parameters etc.

A simplified version of this:

```
<option value="@value">@ChildContent</option>   

@code {
    [Parameter] public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public string value { get; set; }
 }
```

I'm using the component in the exactly the same way as the option tag, and html-wise, the code renders exactly the same.

It all appears to work fine, but doesn't do an initial bind eg. the top option is always selected, but only visibly - the Value is empty string.

Comment: use @key like this <option @key="@value" value="@value">@ChildContent</option>

Comment: @AliBorjian Unfortunately that doesn't work. Still sat undefined, showing top option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further investigation this has been identified as a bug.

Links to two issues on GitHub dotnet/aspnetcore:

[elements inserted dynamically during same diff as  don't get auto-selected #21453](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/21453)

[Blazor: Dynamic  not setting selected value #21432](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/21432)

Answer (score 1):

You just need to create custom razor component -> CustomOption.razor with such content

```
    <option value="@value" class="@specAttribute">@ChildContent</option>

@code {
    [Parameter] public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public string value { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public string specAttribute { get; set; }
}
```

And then use it:

```
<InputSelect  @bind-Value="@language">
    <CustomOption value="English" specAttribute="list-item">English</CustomOption>
    <CustomOption value="Spanish" specAttribute="list-item">Spanish</CustomOption>
</InputSelect>
```

Comment: This is the same code as in my original post. The issue is not the custom option tag, it's that it does not bind an initial value. If you create the select twice (one with option and one with CustomOption) and set language to "Spanish", the standard select will be correct but the custom one will say English (it isn't even set to English, it's just the top of the list)